# python logging - default value to extra parameters

Tags: python, django, logging

I would like to set default value to extra parameter `user_id`. I've written filter:

```
class SystemLogFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if not record.user_id:
            record.user_id = '--'

        return True
```

But I've got this error: `AttributeError: 'LogRecord' object has no attribute 'user_id'`

How can I get access to `user_id` parameter?

This is my logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'system_log': {
            'format': '%(asctime)-15s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s - %(user_id)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'system2': {
            '()': 'system.logging2.SystemLogFilter',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/system.log')),
            'formatter': 'system_log',
            'filters': ['system2'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
         },
    }
}
```

Comment: I have written a small library for that: https://github.com/svisser/logaugment

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `hasattr` (a built-in function) to check whether the log record has the desired attribute. If not, then you can set a default value.

For example:

```
class SystemLogFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if not hasattr(record, 'user_id'):
            record.user_id = '--'
        return True
```

and then you need to attach this new filter to some logger (for example `root` logger) somewhere in your application (preferably the start):

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addFilter(SystemLogFilter())
```

Comment: hi brother where to write this class

Comment: @vijinselvaraj I've added an example